# Cannot uninstall Java JRE 1.7 32bits

Tags: java, uninstallation

For some reason my firefox browser stopped detecting java and now I can't run anything with java on it because it says that it's not installed, so I went to add/remove programs and tried to uninstall java but it just won't get removed.

http://rcupload.com/images/IDSnu.png

So when I try to uninstall it (Java(TM) 7 Update 5) a little window appears with a progress bar, after it completes it disappears but Java is still there..

this is the window that appears:
http://rcupload.com/images/HLUwZ.png

Here's what I tried to do:

1) Use CCleaner to uninstall it:
- I choose the program, press uninstall and it disappears, but when I refresh the list it will still be there. I also tried using the "remove entry" button in CCleaner and i just get a message saying "cannot delete msi installer'.

2) I tried using JavaRA:
- I ran it as administrator, clicked "remove older versions", and I got the message that Java JDK 1.7 was uninstalled and all the files, but now I see that there is no folder for it at "C:\program files (x86)\Java\" (there was one inside before, called something like jre-7) and the icon in the installed programs appears like a white box instead of looking the like the java logo.

3) I tried downloading java and installing it:
- I run it, it downloads and it gets to a screen where it asks me if I want to install a toolbar, I click next and I get this message:
http://rcupload.com/images/xiCIu.png

- I also tried changing the destination folder. same result.

--
Resumed: I need to get rid of Java(TM) 7 Update 5 but the uninstaller seems not to work and files are missing.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Two questions:  1.  Did you check `about:plugins` and see if the Java plugin was disabled?  2.  Did you try uninstalling the software in Safe Mode instead of using CCleaner - which may or may not guarantee a full uninstallation?

Comment: @Makoto I did look into my firefox plugins and all I see from java is "Java Deployment Toolkit 7.0.50.255", I don't think that's the java runtime plugin tho.. I also tried using safe-mode, same result as any other option.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same exact problem, and solved it using Microsoft Fix it tool, here:
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

Finally, a Microsoft troubleshooter that actually works !

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced this before my self. Here's my guess. One may say this is a 'harsh' way to remove and cause system in-stability. But I don't see any other way with the given details.

**Please don't continue if you don't understand every step. This is almost what the un-installer does behind the scenes. You will have to do them manually.**

- First Un-install Firefox.

  - *It doesn't detect the Java version installed for some reason where the Java installer does. you'll have to re-install it later when everything is fine.*
- Delete (i mean, backup) your JRE folder in 'Program Files'
- Open regedit, and find the key for Java Runtime under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and delete (export it first, just in case) the key. (You'll have to go through each key and see the `DisplayName` for them.)

  - *This will remove the entry in Add/Remove programs and Windows will think there's no Java.*
- Remove Java path from your System's Environment variables.

  - *This will cause some apps that check for Java to decide that there's no Java installed.*
- Run the un installer again (if it's still visible in Add/Remove Programs).

  - *If Windows still has the reference to the uninstaller, this will cause it to update it self and remove any references because there's no registry entry, and no program files.*
- Reboot the machine.

  - *This will flush any waiting changes, unregister stuff .etc.*

Try installing Java again. (*Installer should not detect that there's Java installed, because there's no Environment variables set, and no registry entries.*)

**Please try this at your own risk. This may cause issues in your system.**

You may get a better answer if posted on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Let us know the results.